# SQL Calculate a cumulative Distinct count per day since the first day of the month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with rows Date, Segment, Area , Province and Billing_nbr. I would also want a *count distinct* on `Billing_nbr where total_revenue > 0` based from the ddate of that row going back to the first day of the month (ie Month To Date Count). This means that it should be a cumulative count of all billing_nbrs from the first day of the month to the date of observation (which is the ddate on each row). This means that if a billing_nbr occurs in the first day, it should also be included in the count for the second day even if it does not occur in the second day but should be counted once if it occurs in both days. And another normal count of the `Billing_nbr where total_revenue > 0` grouped by other columns. Below is the data that I have:

I have the Join Below but its giving me similar figures on both counts:

```
SELECT 
    MAIN_TABLE.*,
    TOT_SUBS_COUNT.N AS A1_SUBSCRIBERS_TOTAL,
    TOT_SUBS_COUNT_MTD.N AS TOTAL_MTD_A1_SUBSCRIBERS
FROM (
        select  
                ddate,
                SUM(TOTAL_REVENUE) AS REVENUE_TOTAL, 
                segment,
                province,
                area
        from CADA_PERMSISDN_DASHBOARD 
        GROUP BY province, area, segment, ddate
        order by ddate
) MAIN_TABLE
JOIN(
    select DDATE, count(DISTINCT BILLING_NBR) AS N, province, area, SEGMENT from CADA_PERMSISDN_DASHBOARD
    WHERE TOTAL_REVENUE > 0
    GROUP BY province, area, segment, ddate
    ORDER BY DDATE
) TOT_SUBS_COUNT ON MAIN_TABLE.DDATE = TOT_SUBS_COUNT.DDATE 
AND MAIN_TABLE.SEGMENT = TOT_SUBS_COUNT.SEGMENT 
AND MAIN_TABLE.PROVINCE = TOT_SUBS_COUNT.PROVINCE 
AND MAIN_TABLE.AREA = TOT_SUBS_COUNT.AREA
JOIN(
    select DDATE, count(DISTINCT BILLING_NBR) AS N, province, area, SEGMENT from CADA_PERMSISDN_DASHBOARD
    WHERE TOTAL_REVENUE > 0
    AND DDATE BETWEEN trunc((DDATE),'month') AND DDATE
    GROUP BY province, area, segment, ddate
    ORDER BY DDATE
) TOT_SUBS_COUNT_MTD ON MAIN_TABLE.DDATE = TOT_SUBS_COUNT_MTD.DDATE 
AND MAIN_TABLE.SEGMENT = TOT_SUBS_COUNT_MTD.SEGMENT
AND MAIN_TABLE.PROVINCE = TOT_SUBS_COUNT_MTD.PROVINCE 
AND MAIN_TABLE.AREA = TOT_SUBS_COUNT_MTD.AREA
```

The first join is for the grouped count and the second join is for the cumulative count from first day of the month up-to the date of observation (which is the ddate of each row) and it has to be grouped by other columns as well. The count columns are aliased A1_SUBSCRIBERS_TOTAL and OTAL_MTD_A1_SUBSCRIBERS respectively. Below is that data I am getting and as you cant see I have identical counts on both columns:

Comment: Why don't you do the count at the insert time, by selecting the count(*) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your data has to do with the query.  But for a sum-to-date in a month, you can use analytic functions, like this:

```
select ddate, segment, province, area,
       sum(total_revenue) as revenue_total,
       sum(sum(total_revenue)) over (partition by trunc(ddate, 'MON') order by ddate) as mtd_revenue_total
from CADA_PERMSISDN_DASHBOARD 
group by province, area, segment, ddate
order by ddate
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need counts (especially a cumulative per day count) not sums. Sums were straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
TO_CHAR(A.ddate, 'YYYY-MM'), 
A.segment, 
A.province, 
A.area,
SUM(CASE WHEN total_revenue > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TOTAL_GT_ZERO,
COUNT(*) TOTAL_SUBSCRIBERS
from CADA_PERMSISDN_DASHBOARD A
group by TO_CHAR(A.ddate, 'YYYY-MM'), A.segment, A.province, A.area
```

From what I understood. But can you provide what you are expecting ?

Comment: I think this what I am looking for. Can you kindly explain how the CASE cumulatively adds to the total?

Comment: The case will return 1 or 0 depending of the value of total_revenu. Sum makes the total.

Comment: Then thats just a count and its not cumulative per day. But thank you for your help.